# Sprites being skipped over in simple sprite change script

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, sprites

Each instance of the prefab in question has a copy of this script on it, but they seem to be interfering with each other in some way.

I would forego prefabs, except the final game I'm prototyping for will use procedural generation for building placement.

The problem is: it skips to dmgSprite2 and dmgSprite3 really frequently, only maybe 1 in 4 buildings performs as it should, going down the line of sprites appropriately.

Can someone explain to me what is happening to cause this?  I tried playing with coroutines and multiple loop iterations and nothing is fixing the issue.  I've been at this all weekend with varying success, but no permanent solutions.

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) //If space is pressed..
    {
        while(collision.gameObject.name == ("Player")) //While Player is colliding..
        {
            BlowUp(); //Initiate sprite change.
            Debug.Log("Blow Up");
            return;
        }
    }       
}



void BlowUp()
{
    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == mainSprite) //If the sprite is mainSprite..
    {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = dmgSprite; //Change to dmgSprite.
            Debug.Log("Check 1");
    }

    else if (spriteRenderer.sprite == dmgSprite) //If the sprite is dmgSprite..
    {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = dmgSprite2; //Change to dmgSprite2.
            Debug.Log("Check 2");
    }

    else if (spriteRenderer.sprite == dmgSprite2) //If the sprite is dmgSprite2..
    {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = dmgSprite3; //Change to dmgSprite3.
            Debug.Log("Check 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it's skipping them, are you seeing the "Check" message for the one that was skipped?

Comment: This shouldn't be causing an issue, but change the `while` to an `if` statement. OnCollisionStay fires once per frame as long as a collider is still in the collider area. The return forces only one iteration of the `while`, so you can just use an `if`. Try making that change, retest, and let us know. There's a slim chance that might be causing issues.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I'm restricted to weekends.  So my "check" debugging is a little confusing, because it will only ever call that message once per initialization no matter how many buildings you BlowUp(), and on initializing sometimes even the first building to run it will sometimes skip to the second or third sprite, but it will call my Check 1 through Check 3 as well as the "BlowUp" debug check, which strangely comes after the Check 1 but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Comment: Also, I initially tried the `if` statement and it's the same issues.  That's why I thought maybe it was an issue of machine time in some way, and I started playing with adding a few second pause coroutine between each time the `BlowUp()` function can run.  The coroutine helped somewhat, because if I take it slowly it doesn't skip **as** often, but that just seems like a temporary patch on a bigger problem somehow.  Any other ideas or ways I could work around this?